# Small Touch Display Recommendation with RS485 Connectivity

Tags: displays

A project needs a small touch display to control an alarm system in public buildings. requiring:

- Touch display (preferably resistive)
- RS485 connectivity (to enable the display to be a good distance from the hardware)
- Cost per display is a consideration when ordered in volume (200 per year or so).

The display doesn't need to be very big (4" or even less would work), and the resolution doesn't really matter either, as long as it's adequate for buttons and text.

If you know how visual elements are configured to the display (for example by using QT), that would be helpful.

Once the prototype has been built, more of the displays will be ordered. Example image:

[image: picture of a similar display with bezel]

Thanks for any help or direction!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

4D Systems offers [many different displays](https://4dsystems.com.au/products/4d-intelligent-hmi-display-modules/gen4-hmi-display-modules).

The key advantages are:

- They offer an RS485 "plugin" for the display ([MOTG-RS485](https://4dsystems.com.au/products/4d-intelligent-hmi-display-modules/gen4-hmi-display-modules/motg-modules/motg-rs485)).
- An IDE suite of software to program and configure the UI of the Display ([Workshop4 IDE](https://4dsystems.com.au/workshop4)).
- Provide [documentation](https://4dsystems.com.au/products/4d-intelligent-hmi-display-modules/gen4-hmi-display-modules/gen4-ulcd-24dt) on how to get the board working.
- Provide "[Starter Kits](https://4dsystems.com.au/products/4d-intelligent-hmi-display-modules/gen4-hmi-display-modules/starter-kits)" to make getting started easy.
- Are reasonably priced, with volume discounts.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

https://www.ebay.com/i/302749391806?chn=ps

https://www.ebay.com/i/302947551880?chn=ps

https://www.ebay.com/i/303039933850?chn=ps

shows three RS485 [touch displays](https://www.google.com/aclk?sa=L&ai=DChcSEwiIysPw_sLpAhXaIK0GHUAPDvcYABB5GgJwdg&sig=AOD64_3Y3EpKvKdrhpcYJrY1L72dwG-9wQ&ctype=5&q=&ved=0ahUKEwjOpb_w_sLpAhWSq54KHdmDCdEQ2CkIows&adurl=).  Please contact the sellers for volume pricing, dimensions for mounting hardware and bezels, and how visual elements are configured to the display.